# Yesod - Angular directive templates

Tags: haskell, yesod

How can I make a handler deliver HTML (using hamlet), whithout wrapping it inside `defaultLayout`?? They will have as root a `div` tag, not something inside a whole `html` tag. Such way should also consider internationalization.

Comment: sorry I got your request wrong - why don't you have a look at the implementation of [`defaultLayout`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-core-1.4.18.2/docs/src/Yesod-Core-Class-Yesod.html#defaultLayout) - it's quite simple and you should be able to adapt it do your needs easily

Answer (score 1):

Using Angular with Yesod works well because angular templating happens inside valid html that hamlet can generate.

Besides the current comment answer you might consider including a lot of templates using script tags inside a layout. I have done this before where there was a front page layout, an app layout, and an admin layout.